# How to write easy to debug/maintain JavaScript Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Event Handler can be written in mainly two ways:

```
<input type="button" onclick="clickFunction()" />
```

or

```
 $('#btnID).click( function(){ .. });
```

Someone has to debug/maintain this code at a later stage. In the first case, we can do "inspect Element" and quickly find what is executed. In the second case, we have to find the right Document Loader code to find where it is assigned.

What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way is to write an event handler (the second option). For reasoning behind this, look at "2. Don’t Write Inline Javascript" in [this great article](http://omniti.com/seeds/javascript-tips-for-non-specialists).

Furthermore, if you are looking to write code thats easier to debug, consider naming your callbacks. This way they will show up in js errors with the function name instead of "in undefined".

```
$('#btnID).click( function someEvent(){ .. });
```

Comment: In this case, the markup will be <input id="btnID" ..>  If the BtnID is reused on multiple pages, with different click handlers, how do I locate where the handler is..

Comment: If it does something different, and has a separate callback, then it should have a different id. Why would you use the same id on a button that does something different?

Comment: The HTML is generated by a script/engine so it does its own thing :-). It assigns a serial number for every control, starting with an initial value. So every page will have a #BTN001.  BTW, what is the advantage of naming anonymous functions?

Comment: @Kostia It isn't uncommon to use something like `btnSubmit` for a submit button on a form. This is something that might occur on many pages. @srini.venigalla in this situation you'll want to compartmentalize your scripts into separate files. You will have common functionality in one script that multiple pages can use, and page-specific scripts each in their own file included only on the relevant pages.

Comment: you can see their name in the debugger stack trace

Comment: @srini.venigalla here is an example from node.js but works the same in plain javascript: http://nodeguide.com/style.html#named-closures

Comment: @Shmiddty I have to disagree. Just because its common doesn't mean its best practice; though I understand there are special cases.

Comment: If two buttons will never exist in the DOM at the same time, there's no reason that they need separate IDs. It would be better to keep functionality separated into individual scripts for each page, thus eliminating any naming conflicts altogether.

Comment: @Kostia what happens is, many code engines implement "templates". when they reuse the templates, you would get repeating ids, so they get serial IDs, but the context in which the template is used determines the handler code. Coding is not the issue. How does the maintainer find where the code is?

Comment: @srini.venigalla I am familiar... but I think the solution is to have things like separate partials for separate functionality (and then rename the ID accordingly). If the functionality is similar, but not identical, I would be inclined to use the same callback function (which is DRY-ER) and have some kind of separation depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

The second method is the preferred method. There are a few reasons for this:

First, it separates presentation from logic. You don't want to have your presentation (HTML) mixed up with your logic because things become hard to maintain. I like to have a single area of JavaScript devoted to "bindings" so that I can easily see where my JavaScript logic hooks into my HTML. But it's important to keep this out of the HTML itself.

Second, it prevents code duplication. The inline method often results in code like this:

```
[ <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeWindow()">X</a> ]
...
<button onclick="closeWindow()">Close Window</button>
```

The problem is that you end up with many different elements referencing a single function or method. If that function or method changes in any way, you'll need to hunt around for all the references. This violates basic anti-code duplication measures. It's much better to do something like this

```
[ <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeWin">X</a> ]
...
<button class="closeWin">Close Window</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".closeWin").on("click", closeWindow);
    });
</script>
```

Third, it allows for a single choke point for certain user actions where you can add a breakpoint for debugging purposes. Sure, you could do this within whatever function is getting called, but having a dedicated binding area just seems to speed things up.

Fourth, it allows for multiple bindings. For instance you might have three buttons, the first two perform one action, the last two perform another action (so the second button performs both actions). You could start throwing multiple lines of JavaScript in your onclick, like this:

```
<button onclick="one();">One</button>
<button onclick="one();two();">Two</button>
<button onclick="two();">Three</button>
```

This looks as ugly as it is. You could also use some awkward intermediate method, like so:

```
<button onclick="one();">One</button>
<button onclick="oneAndTwo();">Two</button>
<button onclick="two();">Three</button>
```

Which is also super-ugly and will become a maintenance nightmare. Or you can do some simple bindings:

```
<button class="actionOne">One</button>
<button class="actionOne actionTwo">Two</button>
<button class="actionTwo">Three</button>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".actionOne").on("click", one);
        $(".actionTwo").on("click", two);
    });
</script>
```

Much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Now, as for your concern about how to determine what event handlers are attached, I don't have a perfect answer, but I do have a pretty good one: Get Google Chrome (this might also work in Safari). When you inspect an element in Google Chrome, it will give you a list of event handlers attached to that element.

If you follow my advice about having a "bindings" section in your JavaScript, it's pretty easy to narrow down what's bound to what. But using Chrome it's even faster and easier. You're welcome to write your code however you see best. Though it's pretty generally accepted that remote bindings are preferred over inline bindings. How to handle them beyond that is subject to your own experience and programming style.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the above excellent answers, I found a tool called Visual Event, which gives a lot of visibility to the Event Handlers.

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event